# PostGIS Manager Load Error

Tags: qgis, postgis

I am using the PostGIS Manager Load data to PostGIS tool on a Windows install and am getting the following error:

```
Something's wrong:
["'shp2pgsql' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\n", 'operable program     or batch file.\n']
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what is wrong?  I am trying to append to an existing table.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like shp2pgsql is not in your execution path. You need to edit your PATH to include the location of shp2pgsql

Comment: No that didn't seem to fix it

Comment: Is it installed on your machine. Somehow you have to point the PostGIS tools to the binary. The error is saying, that whatever called shp2pgsql is not some place the program can find it.